# Logging Javascript / Jquery errors and Exceptions

Tags: javascript, error-handling

One thing I notice i javascript / jquery web architectures is that it seems very easy for exceptions to get swallowed and go unnoticed. I'm thinking what would be really good is if anytime your web tier had a javascript exception, information about it was sent on a AJAX request back to your server so at least you could log information about it.

I am wondering there has to be some framework feature that already does this as I think it would be a really useful feature. Anyone know of any framework, feature or library that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: you could build your own logging mechanism. i'm making one myself.

Comment: adding 'use strict'; to your js file could help http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: I've sold Muscula years ago and it is now a paid service]

You have to tak a lot of things into account when building your own solution.
For example you will see a lot of noise generated by JavaScript errors in plugins, 10-20% of all errors logged.
Grouping the errors intelligently is an extremely hard problem, because of the very different error messages you get for different browsers and versions.
Also you don't want to log 1,000 errors pr user if you have an error in a mousemove event.
And there is a ton of other stuff to consider.

We've build a SaaS solution like the one you ask for [Muscula](http://muscula.com). We're in private beta at the moment, but working very hard to release. We've already monitored more than 100 million pageviews for JavaScript errors, and we log more than 1 million JavaScript errors a week. And beyound the issues I mention above we also have tackled the problem of displaying errors in minified JavaScript as pretty printed, integration with Goggle Analytics and much much more.

You install Muscula like Google Analytics, just copy a script to your page, and you are logging JavaScript errors.

Comment: +1 Allan.  I use Muscula today and am really impressed.  Nice work!

Comment: I sold Muscula about a year ago

Answer (score 4):

There probably are, but it isn't hard to implement yourself. Just hook an event handler to `window` for the `error` event, and make the AJAX request there.

Arguments that will be passed to your event handler, in order, are: the error message as a string, the URL where the error was raised, also a string, the line number where the error was raised, followed finally by the event object.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own, but it can be a bit tricky because you can get flooded with errors, and sending many ajax requests can compound the problem.  Error logging must be debounced, and god forbid your error tracking code produces and error on some obscure browser.    There are a couple of SaaS products with free plans that are worth looking at:

http://errorception.com/

http://www.exceptionhub.com/

I would try those, and then if they don't suite your needs, then you can roll you own.